# SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::send_receive: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: web-services, perl, client, client-side, perl-module

I tried to connect server (I implemented the client side) using SOAP::Lite module
during my debug, I encounter with error of SOAP version which solved by:
    -> soapversion('1.2')
    -> envprefix('soap12');

Now, I have issue that I got below error:
SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::send_receive: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
and then is also write after:
The security context token is expired or is not valid. The message was not processed
Is there any connection between both?

My code is:
my $soap = SOAP::Lite
    -> uri('$uri_address')
    -> on_action( sub { join '/', '$uri_address', $_[1] } )
    -> proxy('$url_address')
    -> soapversion('1.2')
    -> envprefix('soap12');

### - Overriding the constant

$SOAP::Constants::DEFAULT_HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE 
   = 'application/soap+xml';

my $method = SOAP::Data->name('HelloWorld')
->attr({xmlns => '$uri_address'});

## The parameters are held in @params

my @params = ( SOAP::Data->name(MyData => $my_string));

my $result = $soap
                        ->call($method => @params);

if ($result->fault)
{
     print "\n\n==========fault happened===========\n\n";
   print $result->faultstring;
}
else
{
   print $result->result;
}

It printed the envelope and then it prints:
SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::send_receive: HTTP::Response=HASH(0x3749874)
SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::send_receive: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Wed, 13 Apr 2011 23:36:26 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Content-Length: 562
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Client-Date: Wed, 13 Apr 2011 23:36:27 GMT
Client-Peer: 10.185.78.22:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/faults:Sendera:BadContextTokenThe security context token is expired or is not valid. The message was not processed.
SOAP::Deserializer::deserialize: ()
SOAP::Parser::decode: ()
SOAP::SOM::new: ()

==========fault happened===========

SOAP::SOM::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Lite::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Serializer::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Data::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Data::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Data::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Data::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Data::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Data::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Transport::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Deserializer::DESTROY: ()
SOAP::Parser::DESTROY: ()

What can be the root cause? pls help...

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a bit of time to familiarise yourself how this Web site works. Learn about how to *format code* in the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), and how to *accept answers* in the [site FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Java answers to this, it looks as though the SSL certificate on the server side might have expired or be corrupted. This is often a problem in a 'test' setup too.

Is it possible to regenerate the certificate or [if pssible] surf to an endpoint using the same certificate, to see whether there's exception messages.

Disclaimer: I'm not a Microsoft dev at all, so this is pretty tentative.